# Read and write to spi eeprom on linux

Tags: linux, spi, eeprom

I want to use my spi eeprom (at25) under debian (Beaglebone Black).
I have edited the device tree, so now i can read and write to eeprom.

There is already a spi-at25-driver in Linux.

Reading from eeprom

```
cat /sys/class/spi_master/spi1/spi1.o/eeprom
```

writing to eeprom

```
echo hello > /sys/class/spi_master/spi1/spi1.o/eeprom
```

But i want to write and read from specific address of the eeprom.
Is there any way to do this within a C-Program?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the eeprom here is mapped to a file representation you can use it as a normal file.

So simply `open` the file, go to the place where you want to read/modify/write with `seek` and do your `write`. Don't forget a `close` or `flush` for the file id.

It is also possible to mmap your file into your memory of the process and access the memory there as a normal array.