# C program example for Read and Write to SPI eeprom on linux

Tags: c, linux, spi, eeprom

I am trying to write 4 bytes to spi eeprom on linux and then read 4 bytes (the last is the important one, I'm working with zybo board), I did all for spi eeprom detection and now I have:

```
/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi32766.0/eeprom
```

In this link: [Read and write to spi eeprom...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100105/read-and-write-to-spi-eeprom-on-linux) Klaus says that is possible to do this using eeprom as a character file, but in this link: [How to read data...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807471/how-to-read-data-from-a-serial-spi-connection-in-c) Sawdust says that this is no possible because this kind of driver are platform driver.

I tried treating eeprom as a character file in C, but the obtained data are incoherent (I did a test in bare-metal code and the SPI device works), maybe because I don't know how data has to be send, Could somebody explain me with a piece of code, how should I read/write to SPI EEPROM?.

Thanks a lot :)

A summary of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int readData(FILE* fp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    char ch = 'a';
    while (1) {
        fp = fopen("/sys/bus/spi/devices/spi32766.0/eeprom", "r+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open /sys/bus/spi/devices/spi32766.0/eeprom for write\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Sending data\n");
        fputs("\x01\x02\x03\x04", fp);//or fputs(four bytes, fp) 
        while (readData(fp) == 0) {
            sleep(1);
        }
        printf("End\n");
        fclose(fp);
        sleep(5);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int readData(FILE* fp) {
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    int retorno = (feof(fp) == NULL);
    printf("Char: %c\n", c);
    printf("Int: %d\n", c);
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: `int retorno = (feof(fp) == NULL);` should fail to compile in `C`.  You should write `int retorno = (c == EOF);`.  You need to call `fseek()` or `rewind()` between `fputs()` and `fgetc()` on the same `FILE`.  Standard streams are probably inappropriate for your purpose.

Comment: @chqrlie: `rewind()` wouldn't be needed for special files, like device nodes or sockets.  The input and output on these are completely separate, and writing doesn't affect the read pointer (in fact, there often is no pointer at all)

Comment: the open has to be against a /dev/something, not against the platform driver.   the second of your links clearly explains this (read the whole thing)

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will try later because I'm not close to my computer now, @user3629249 I know that the normal way is using /dev/something but how do you create a "/dev/something" for a platform driver?, thank you.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: special files or not, the standard says it is undefined behaviour.  Accessing device nodes with a standard stream is not a good idea.  `open`, `read`, `write` is much more direct and predictable.

Comment: @chqrlie: Implementation-defined, not undefined.  Everything related to actual semantics of file access is highly implementation-specific; the C and C++ Standards really only specify the arguments.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: with all due respect, the C11 Standard does explicitly list in Annex J.2 Undefined Behaviour: *- An output operation on an update stream is followed by an input operation without an intervening call to the fflush function or a file positioning function, or an input operation on an update stream is followed by an output operation with an intervening call to a file positioning function (7.21.5.3).*  Some implementations may define the behaviour, but it would be a quirk.  Trying to control flash memory operation with standard streams seems awkward.